# Showing Error After Declaring Variable

Tags: sql-server

Showing Error After Declaring Variable.

**Incorrect syntax near 'USP_CRUD_JWELORDERS2'.**

When i run this code it is running fine

```
USP_CRUD_JWELORDERS2 @operation = 'DisplayHelper' ,@memberid = 'LYM37361224'   , @orderdt='01/01/2009'
```

But After declaring a variable shows error.

```
declare @memberid_ varchar(20); set @memberid_ = 'LYM37361224';
USP_CRUD_JWELORDERS2 @operation = 'DisplayHelper' ,@memberid = @memberid_   , @orderdt='01/01/2009'
```

Comment: **Incorrect syntax near 'USP_CRUD_JWELORDERS2'.**

Comment: Thanks for this question. I didn't know that the exec was at all optional. You've taught me something today (+1 for that)
MSDN: You do not have to specify the EXECUTE keyword when you execute stored procedures and the statement is the first one in a batch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `USP_CRUD_JWELORDERS2` is stored procedure.
 Add `EXEC` before `USP_CRUD_JWELORDERS2` in your modified script.

```
declare @memberid_ varchar(20); 
set @memberid_ = 'LYM37361224';
EXEC USP_CRUD_JWELORDERS2 @operation = 'DisplayHelper' ,@memberid = @memberid_ , @orderdt='01/01/2009'
```